# IOS - Add Cells at particular index with uistepper

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard

I am displaying dynamic data in UITableView with checkbox button in it. When User Select Checkbox button it will show UIStepper just below it. I dont know how to achieve this, what I exactly required is mentioned in the url below.
[Target To achieve](http://imgur.com/6QPU9VS)

I have just displayed the data in UITableView yet as mentioned in the code below. I don't know how to achieve this whether should i add cells below every index when user select checkbox or there some other good approach that i should follow.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [getNutrients count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NutrientCell";

   UITableViewCell *nutrientCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    nutrientCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture_bg.png"]];

    UILabel *nutrientLabel = (UILabel*)[nutrientCell viewWithTag:1];
    nutrientLabel.text = [[getNutrients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];

    return nutrientCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has property to insert row or section. 
You can use insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
For insert and delete row respectively.